# Javascript Variable and Object

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript. I want to ask you. I have this code:

```
var fullname = 'David'; 
var obj = {
  fullname: 'Jhon', 
  prop: { 
    fullname: 'Angle', 
    getFullname: function () { 
      return this.fullname; 
    } 
  } 
}; 
console.log(obj.prop.getFullname()); 
var test = obj.prop.getFullname; console.log(test());
```

The result is

```
Angle --> console.log(obj.prop.getFullName());
```

and

```
David --> console.log(test());
```

Can you explain that? why the result is different? Thanks

Comment: `obj.prop.getFullName()` calls the function getFullName, `getFullname` gets the attribute. (`this` in the function = window, hence why it gets david also)

Comment: common javascript mistake, "this" is a funny, doing test = somefunc, is not the same as in other languages, (pointer to function).  if you want to do that sort of thing in javascript you will need to use bind.  eg. var test = obj.prop.getFullname.bind(obj.prop).

Comment: Urgh I was too slow. Here my answer: It's all about context.

Inside the 'prop', the 'this' links to the 'prop' itself.
But if you take just the method, the context of 'this' changes to the global context (window).